# How do I disable the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH option in php?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

So this is what I have so far:

```
self::$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_exec(self::$connection); // Do a request that uses Basic Auth
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, false); // <-- Not working as expected - I want to disable Basic Auth here
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_URL, $anotherURL);
curl_exec(self::$connection); // <-- Not working as expected - I want to do a request that does NOT use Basic Auth.
```

So, if I initialized the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH option to CURLAUTH_BASIC, how would I go about disabling it?

I need to use the same handle (that is self::$connection) in order to have a persistent HTTP connection.

Comment: You should try 0 instead of false...

Comment: It still sends the HTTP request using Basic Auth.

Comment: Maybe you have to reset the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps anyone, this is what I ended up doing:

```
if ($enableBasicAuth){
    self::$httpHeaders['Authorization'] = 'Basic '.base64_encode("$username:$password");    
}
else if (isset(self::$httpHeaders['Authorization'])){
    unset(self::$httpHeaders['Authorization']);    // Disable Basic Auth
}

// Convert the $httpHeaders array into a format that is used by CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
$httpHeadersRaw = array();
foreach (self::$httpHeaders as $header=>$value){
    $httpHeadersRaw[] = $header.': '.$value;
}
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeadersRaw); // Set the HTTP Basic Auth header manually
```

Basically I just manually enable/disable Basic Auth using the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? It's the only solution that works so far...so what if it's not the *official* method.

Comment: this also works on the command line, if e.g. you inherit `user = foo:bar` from a curlrc file, then you can do `curl -H Authorization: http://example.com` to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Just set it again to nothing...

```
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, 0);
```

This is a bitmask, and 0 would set none of the bits...

If this is a consecutive request, you might also want to reset the user/password:

```
curl_setopt(self::$connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '');
```

Comment: It still sends a Basic Auth header...:( After I tried both of your lines.

Comment: Hm. as another idea, try changing URL to another domain and then back? cause unless `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH` is on, curl should reset authentication details on host switch...

Comment: I'm not sure if that will keep the connection persistent to the original domain...

Comment: Whoever downvoted everything here, please comment, and provide an alternative if you have one.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the manpage for curl says passing `--user` (which is, I think, the command-line equivalent of `CURLOPT_USERPWD`) with an empty value for the username part causes the logged in user's name to be used

Answer (score 0):

As Baseer explained, the trick is that you should never rely on `curl_setopt_array()` but always set the entire array of options directly on `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` with `curl_setopt()`. If you then want to drop the basic authentication you can simply remove the 'Authorization' line from the headers.

Here is an example that is easy to understand:

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');

// Do a request with basic authentication.
$headers = [
  'Accept: */*',
  'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('username:password'),
];
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($handle);

// Do a subsequent request without basic authentication.
$headers = [
  'Accept: */*',
];
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($handle);
?>
```