# Reading data via OData: how to specify the authentication scheme via curl/RCurl?

Tags: r, https, odata, rcurl

I'd like to read some data via a HTTPS [OData](http://www.odata.org/) connection and the data source requires the `Basic` authentication scheme. I'm familiar with the usual [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)/[RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) options (such as `username`, `userpwd` and `cainfo`), but I'm not sure on how to pass the authentication scheme information.

This is some C# code from a colleague that worked for another application:

```
var bind = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
bind.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
```

So I guess I need to find out what the RCurl equivalent for the `.NET` value `System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic` would be in the R/curl world?

---

This is what I came up with so far:

### Disregarding any authentication information

```
web_page = getURL(
  url = "https://xxxx.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cc_home_analytics.svc/path/to/ressource", 
  username = "<username>",
  userpwd = "*****",
  cainfo = "inst/ssl/ca-bundle.pem"
)
```

This is the answer I'm getting (translated from German via Google Chrome):

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict / / EN"
    "Http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <Meta name = "generator" content =
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title> Logon Error Message </ title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
  <style type="text/css">
  / * <! [CDATA [* /
      body {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 333333; background-color: # FFFFFF; } Td {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 70%; color: # 333333; {H1} H2 {} } P {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 333333; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; Ul {} Li} {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 33333; margin-top: 4px; Emphasize} {color: # 333333; background-color:. # C8E3FF; padding: 5px;} note {color: # CC6600;. } A {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: underline; color: # 336699; } A: visited {color: # 001166; } A: hover {text-decoration: none; }
      / *]]> * /
  </ Style>
</ Head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1> Login Failed </ h1> <br />

        <h2> What happened? </ h2>

        <p> Calling the URL
        https://my310094.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cc_home_analytics.svc/RPCRMQUFU_Q0001QueryResults
        was aborted due to incorrect credentials. </ p>
      </ Td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td> </ td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="emphasize">
        <strong> Note </ strong> <br />

        <ul>
          <li> The application was running in the system KHN. </ li>

          <li> The application was for the client 015 and the user and the
          Performed language. </ Li>
        </ Ul>
      </ Td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td> </ td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        </ p>

        <h2> What can you do? </ h2>

        <ul>
          <li> Check the indication of the clients, users and
          the password for typos. </ li>

          <li> If you do not have a user ID, contact
          your system administrator. </ li>
        </ Ul> <br />

        <p class="note"> error code:
        ICF-LE-https-c:015-l:-u:-a:1-c:015-l:-r:0-T:1-C:1-U:8-P:-L:6-X:00163E0746C81EE484C92B972817350C_00163E0746C81EE484C92B969D80750C_1-x:00163E0746C81EE484C92B972817550C</p><br />


        <p> HTTP 401 - Unauthorized <br /> </ p>

        <p> Your SAP Internet Communication Framework Team </ p>
      </ Td>
    </ Tr>
  </ Table>
</ Body>
</ Html>
```

### Specifying `httpauth`

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173677/how-do-i-disable-the-curlopt-httpauth-option-in-php), I tried the following:

```
web_page = getURL(
  url = "https://xxxx.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cc_home_analytics.svc/path/to/ressource", 
  username = "<username>",
  userpwd = "*****",
  cainfo = "inst/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",
  httpauth = "CURLAUTH_BASIC"
)
```

This time, the answer looks different ((translated from German via Google Chrome):

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict / / EN"
    "Http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <Meta name = "generator" content =
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title> Logon Error Message </ title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
  <style type="text/css">
/ * <! [CDATA [* /
  body {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 333333; background-color: # FFFFFF; } Td {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 70%; color: # 333333; {H1} H2 {} } P {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 333333; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; Ul {} Li} {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; color: # 33333; margin-top: 4px; Emphasize} {color: # 333333; background-color:. # C8E3FF; padding: 5px;} note {color: # CC6600;. } A {font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: underline; color: # 336699; } A: visited {color: # 001166; } A: hover {text-decoration: none; }
  / *]]> * /
  </ Style>
</ Head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1> Login Failed </ h1> <br />

        <h2> What happened? </ h2>

        <p> Calling the URL
        https://my310094.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cc_home_analytics.svc was
        aborted due to incorrect credentials. </ p>
      </ Td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td> </ td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="emphasize"> <strong> Note </ strong> <br />
      The application was running in the system KHN. Here were no
      Credentials provided. </ Td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td> </ td>
    </ Tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        </ p>

        <h2> What can you do? </ h2>

        <ul>
          <li> If you do not have a user ID, contact
          your system administrator. </ li>
        </ Ul> <br />

        <p class="note"> error code:
        ICF-LE-https-c:015-l:-u:-a:0-c:015-l:-r:99-T:-C:1-U:-P:-L:6-X:00163E0746C81EE484CA0C65DC12398A_00163E0746C81EE484CA0C65D826798A_1-x:00163E0746C81EE484CA0C65DC12598A</p><br />


        <p> HTTP 401 - Unauthorized <br /> </ p>

        <p> Your SAP Internet Communication Framework Team </ p>
      </ Td>
    </ Tr>
  </ Table>
</ Body>
</ Html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This really easy with httr:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://xxxx.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cc_home_analytics.svc/path/to/ressource"
r <- GET(url, authenticate("<username>", "*****", "basic"))
stop_for_status(r)
content(r)
```

(In httr 0.4, you'll be able to drop "basic", since basic auth is now the default)

Comment: Great, that sounds promising! Thx!

Comment: Aweseome, works a treat! Just out of interest: could you tell me, what the internal RCurl/cURL setting would be that corresponds to the basic authentication method?

Comment: @Rappster `httpauth = 1L`