# How to authenticate OData connection in R

Tags: r, odata

I am looking to use the [OData package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OData/index.html). How do I perform basic authentication using the package?

I have been able to use `httr` and authenticate:

```
resultRaw   <- GET(url, (authenticate(user,pw, type = "basic")))
```

Then, I have extracted the `content` from `resultRaw` and processed it. I am trying to use the OData package instead of that workflow.

Comment: Will be great to receive some help.

Comment: Duplicate, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907288/reading-data-via-odata-how-to-specify-the-authentication-scheme-via-curl-rcurl